# JavaFX Imageview invalid URL

Tags: java, image, javafx

Trying to use JavaFX to load an image.

```
//this line causes an error. It's the first line of the start method
Image image = new Image("/61.jpg");
```

No matter where I put the image, it causes an error. I have it in the root directory. Using an absolute path also gives an error. I have the image stored in `NeatbeansProjects/MyProjectName`.

Using `Windows 10` and `Netbeans`. Have read multiple guides on this, and multiple stack overflow questions about this. None seem to be able to fix this.

Thank you.

EDIT: SOLVED. By formatting like this: Image("file:assets/images/61.jpg")
to access MyProjectName/assets/images/61.jpg

thanks all!

Comment: From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html): "All URLs supported by URL can be passed to the constructor. If the passed string is not a valid URL, but a path instead, the Image is searched on the classpath in that case." So with the code you posted, it will search for the image in the root of the classpath. Make sure NetBeans is deploying the image file to the build folder (look in `NetbeansProjects/MyProjectName/build/classes`).

Comment: Also try `new Image(getClass().getResource("/61.jpg").toExternalForm())`, though if your current code isn't working, I would expect that to throw a null pointer exception.

Comment: Put the image in the classes directory. Still not working. Absolute paths also don't work. EDIT: James_D, your 2nd suggestion worked! somehow.. but 

most of my images are in MyProjectName/assets/images  

how do I access them from THERE, without using absolute file paths? And why does the getClass().getResource work but the first thing I was doing doesn't?

Comment: Probably need to remove the leading `/` from the original version. You should **not** manually copy the image to `classes`: you should make sure NetBeans is configured to copy it there for you.

Comment: Okay, so removing the leading / allows me to access the image and display it! If it's in the MyProjectName folder. But how do I access a subfolder, like MyProjectName/assets?

    new Image("file://assets//images//61.jpg");

just displays a black box instead of my image

Comment: Surely then any of `new Image("assets/images/61.jpg")` or `new Image(getClass().getResource("/assets/images/61.jpg").toExternalForm())` (note leading `/`) or `new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("assets/image/61.jpg").toExternalForm())` would work

Comment: All of those pieces of code cause an Exception. :( null point exception or invalid URL exception.

Comment: So what is the location of the `deployed` image (i.e. under the `build/classes` folder). Using a `file://` URL will not work once you deploy the application as a jar file.